# Parametro String no iReport

Tags: ireport

Tenho um cadastro de Contrato onde possui um editor de texto e o usuário pode editar o texto do contrato, porém neste texto terá informações como Empresa e Titular do Plano que são dinâmicas e como o texto é passado completo para o relatório.

Preciso saber se é possível receber um string e dentro dela constar outras variáveis que o iReport já possui.

Ex:
O Contrato XYZ com a Empresa $P{razaoSocial}, $P{cnpj}, residente $P{enderecoEmpresa}, firma contrato com o cliente $P{nomeCliente}...

Como estes texto muda e o proprio usuário que efetuar a edição, não posso somente usar a variável, o que posso e deixar disponível as opões que ele pode usar se quiser exibir dentro do seu texto, porém não consegui fazer funcionar ainda.

Comment: Amigo, esse texto: "O Contrato XYZ com a Empresa $P{razaoSocial}, $P{cnpj}, residente $P{enderecoEmpresa}, firma contrato com o cliente $P{nomeCliente}." é sempre fixo? Digo, os únicos valores que são diferentes são o $P{razaoSocial}, $P{cnpj}... ? Caso seja, você pode antes de gerar o relatório, criar um lógica para filtrar esses valores baseado na posição deles (lembrando que o texto tem que ser sempre igual) e depois mandar para o IReport. Não funcionaria ?

Comment: O todo é preenchido pelo usuário do sistema, possui um editor de texto que ele pode mudar a hora que desejar, então pensei em deixar uma msg na tela tipo:
Para utilizar o nome do usuário adicione isto: $P{nomeCliente}
E que o iReport conseguisse ler, pois lá a única coisa que recebo por parâmetro é $P{textoContrato} que vem todo o texto inclusive estes parâmetros dentro, porém ele esta imprimindo como String fixa.]

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido Utilizando:

Example 6.3. Using built-in functions

```
msg("Total cost is {0}", $F{TOTAL})
msg("Matched {0} products out of {1}", $F{MATCHED}, $P{TOTAL})
```